# How to 'init' the code using gitflow?

Tags: git, git-flow

I am new using gitflow, I undertood it, read about it, watched the videos and everything looks great, I just have a doubt that few exercises explain and others start explaining when the repo already got a "base code" .

I have my Git server and I want to use gitflow with an existing code, my question is, when I create the repository, should, directly to the master, commit the code? or I should start the branches as develop and so on to commit the first realease with the base code?

Its not really clear for me, if you can gie me a clue I will be glad.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have existing code that's been deployed or shipped, you should commit to the master branch.

Comment: using the git flow or just make git commit -am 'comment' and 
$ git push origin master?

Comment: @jpganz18: I think you're just going to have to commit something to master (`git commit`) to begin.